# CLI CURL -> PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl

How can I translate this curl command so that it works in a PHP script?

```
curl --request POST --data-binary '@import.xml' --header "Content-Type: application/atom+xml" --header "Content-Length: 378" "http://url.com"
```

this don't work:

```
$data = array('file'=>$filename);                    

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/atom+xml',
        'Content-Length: 378'
    );

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'httpL//url.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);  
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm having a tough time translating something similar to this.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/atom+xml'
    ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://siteurl.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents($filename));  
curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing would be to read the file into a string and then provide that string to the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS options. That feature of reading into a string is not provided by libcurl but is done by the command line client and I don't think the PHP/CURL binding offers the equivalent.

The command line uses --data-binary which corresponds to a CURLOPT_POSTSFIELDS with a string, not a hash array as the array will turn the post in to a multipart post (which the command line does with -F, --form). Also, the custom request set to POST is totally superfluous.

Usually, running the command line with "--libcurl test.c" is a good way to get a first draft version of a C program using the C API, but as the PHP API is very similar that should work as decent start in most cases.

Edit: and custom changing/providing the "Content-Length:" header is never a good idea unless you know perfectly well what you're doing. libcurl will always provide one that is generated based on the data you pass on to it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = array('file'=> '@' . $filename);
```

You need to prepend the filename with a '@' to tell CURL it's actually a filename and not just a string. The headers are not required either, as CURL will fill them in itself.

Comment: From manual: "To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path."
don't work...

Comment: Try doing `$result = curl_exec($ch); if ($result === false) { die(curl_error());`. Never assume the curl request succeeded - always check return values.

Comment: >> The headers are not required either, as CURL will fill them in itself.
but in CLI CURl they are necessarily

Comment: @jocky: yeah, but OP is trying to do it in PHP... and there they're not required.

Comment: PHP CURL ends with succes, but result not right - in CLI CURL it's another

Comment: i'm trying import blog by this instruction:
To import the export file, create a POST request to the following 

URL with the contents of the export file as the request data and application/atom+xml as the content type:

POST http://www.blogger.com/feeds/blogID/archive/full

(http://code.google.com/intl/uk/apis/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html)

and in CLI CURL it success, but I need import from php

Comment: YES!!!

    $upload = file_get_contents($filename);
    ...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $upload);

Comment: This answer is wrong.

 The command line uses --data-binary which corresponds to a POSTSFIELDS with a *string*, not a hash array as the array will turn the post in to a multipart. Also, the custom request set to POST is totally superfluous.