# How to write curl code in PHP

Tags: php, curl

Curl code I am using in php but it is not working

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/unsubscribes \
    -F address='bob@example.com' \
    -F tag='tag1'
```

Comment: Post your PHP code and we can help with it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CLI CURL -> PHP CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749431/cli-curl-php-curl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$ch = curl_init();                    // initiate curl
        $url = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/unsubscribes'; 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "&address=" . $address . "&tag=" . $tag ); // define what you want to post
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the output in string format
        $output = curl_exec($ch); // execute
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Not getting any responce if i print $output and email is not send to mailgun unsubscribe list

Answer (score 0):

**CRUL to PHP code**

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/unsubscribes");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "api" . ":" . "YOUR_API_KEY");

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```